# Why rxjs debounceTime does not work on observables created using 'of' operator?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6, debouncing

Using `angular 7` and `rxjs 6`:

```
<input (input)="onChange($event.target.value)">
```

**Why the following does not debounce?**

```
onChange(val: string) {
  of(val)
    .pipe(        
      debounceTime(300)        
  ).subscribe(valx => {
    console.log(valx);
  });
}
```

**But this does:**

```
  searchTerm$: Subject<string> = new Subject();

  this.searchTerm$.pipe(      
    debounceTime(300),    
  ).subscribe(val => {
   console.log(val);
  });


onChange(val: string) {   
  this.searchTerm$.next(val);
}
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it no log anything or does it not debounce?

Comment: @NunoSousa, I have edited the question, but it does not debounce.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This isn't because of `of()`. In your first example every time you call `onChange($event.target.value)` you're creating a new chain with its own `debounceTime` and its own timer. So it never debounces anything because every input change has its own chain.

However, if you use `Subject` (like in your second example) and push all events through `this.searchTerm$.next(val)` then you have just one chain where each event is pushed at the top and then debounced as you expect.

Answer (score 3):

Consider your logic. You will create a finalised observer for each onChanges. It doesn't debounce because the observer is already finalized, and debounce is to prevent emitting one, in the off-chance that another one comes. So it needs at least **two** emitions to be justifiable (or more ), and that can't happen if the observer is created in the callback.

Comment: This is the correct answer because it cant be debounce anything which is already completed!